# Trying to check if $_POST exists

Tags: php

I don't really know what to call this question, but I have this code:

```
    <?php

include 'connect.php';
include 'functions.php';

$u_id = $_GET['u_id'];
$u_name = $_GET['username'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$post1 = $_POST[''];

if ($type == 'a') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET type='b' WHERE id='$u_id'");
    header('location: admin.php?type=user');
} else if ($type == 'b') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET type='d' WHERE id='$u_id'");
    header('location: admin.php?type=user');
} else if ($type == 'd') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET type='a' WHERE id='$u_id'");
    header('location: admin.php?type=user');
} else {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET type='d' WHERE id='$u_id'");
    header('location: admin.php?type=user');
}

if ($user_level >= 2) {
    mysql_connect("...", "...", "...");
    mysql_select_db("dojo");
    mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET kills='0', deaths='0', wins='0', money='0' WHERE name='$username'");
    header('location: profile');
}

mysql_connect("...", "...", "...");
mysql_select_db("adminpanel");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$private = $row['private'];

if ($private == 'true') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET private='false' WHERE username='$username'");
    header('location: profile');
    exit();
} else if ($private == 'false') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET private='true' WHERE username='$username'");
    header('location: profile');
    exit();
}
?>
```

But the thing is, when I click a button from the page, it will do all of these, so how can I make sure that it will only execute one of them, for example let's say I clicked a button on my profile saying Make Profile Private, then when I do that it will only execute

```
   if ($private == 'true') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET private='false' WHERE username='$username'");
    header('location: profile');
    exit();
} else if ($private == 'false') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET private='true' WHERE username='$username'");
    header('location: profile');
    exit();
}
```

How can I do that?

EDIT:

I've changed a bit in the options.php file, but I still can't get this to work.. I have set the id of the button to resetstats and changeprivacy

```
    <?php

include 'connect.php';
include 'functions.php';

if (isset($_POST['resetstats'])) {
$type = $_GET['type'];
$u_name = $_GET['username'];
$u_id = $_GET['u_id'];
if ($user_level >= 2) {
    mysql_connect("...", "...", "...");
    mysql_select_db("dojo");
    mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET kills='0', deaths='0', wins='0', money='0' WHERE name='$username'");
    header('location: profile');
}
}

if (isset($_POST['changeprivacy'])) {
mysql_connect("...", "...", "...");
mysql_select_db("adminpanel");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$private = $row['private'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$u_name = $_GET['username'];
$u_id = $_GET['u_id'];
if ($private == 'true') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET private='false' WHERE username='$username'");
    header('location: profile');
} else if ($private == 'false') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET private='true' WHERE username='$username'");
    header('location: profile');
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried isset($_POST["postname"]) ?

Comment: I think i just figured it out, I gave each button an ID so I just checked if $_POST['changeprivacy'] then it will execute query, but thanks anyways @EddA.

Comment: @EddA. Hmm, I did the isset thing, and now it just takes me to `options.php?private=true&username=ImSchnebz` but then it just stys there, doesn't redirect me back to my profile, and doesn't update the query

Comment: isset just checks if the $_POST or $_GET exists. It will not affect the redirect. If your application is not redirecting on where it should be. It is a different story.

Comment: @EddA. Yeah, but the weird thing is though, when I click Make Profile Private, it works fine, but when I try to use the other functions, I get errors like: `Notice: Undefined index: resetstats in C:\xampp\htdocs\options.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined index: private in C:\xampp\htdocs\options.php on line 37`

Comment: @Schnebz could you show us what is on line `26` & `37` on your `options.php` file.

Comment: do you have resetstats name on option.php? or how many resetstats do you have on option.php?

Comment: well, can you do  if(isset($_POST["resetstats"])) do something here; else do something here; ...

Comment: @EddA. I've edited the question, try take a look now.

Comment: so basically it does not return to profile right? If this is the url, options.php?private=true&username=ImSchnebz.. is the changeprivacy and resetstats set? it seems that it will only redirect if those are set.

Comment: if you want to redirect it back to profile even if no process has done on options.php.. you can add header('location: profile'); on the very bottom of the page.

Comment: @EddA. Yeah, but there would be no point of that, cause my whole point is to execute a query...

Comment: I'm a little confused on your response.. does it query?

Comment: @EddA. That's the problem, it won't query

Comment: Ohh okay.. got it.. what are these by the way changeprivacy and resetstats? are they button?

Comment: @EddA.

`echo "<a id='resetstats' class='btn btn-danger' href='options.php?resetstats&username=$username'>Reset Your Stats</a>";`

Comment: if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0){ //your code }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you do something like this? I added action on the url

```
if ($user_level >= 2){
    if (($kills || $deaths) == 0) {         
        echo "<a class='btn btn-danger' disabled='disabled' href='#'>Reset Your Stats</a>";
    } 
    else{       
        echo "<a id='resetstats' class='btn btn-danger' href='options.php?action=resetstats&username=$username'>Reset Your Stats</a>"; 
    } 
}
```

and on your options.php

```
 <?php

include 'connect.php';
include 'functions.php';

$action = $_GET['action'];

if ($action == 'resetstats') {
$type = $_GET['type'];
$u_name = $_GET['username'];
$u_id = $_GET['u_id'];
if ($user_level >= 2) {
    mysql_connect("...", "...", "...");
    mysql_select_db("dojo");
    mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET kills='0', deaths='0', wins='0', money='0' WHERE name='$username'");
    header('location: profile');
}
}

if ($action == 'changeprivacy') {
mysql_connect("...", "...", "...");
mysql_select_db("adminpanel");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$private = $row['private'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$u_name = $_GET['username'];
$u_id = $_GET['u_id'];
if ($private == 'true') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET private='false' WHERE username='$username'");
    header('location: profile');
} else if ($private == 'false') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET private='true' WHERE username='$username'");
    header('location: profile');
}
}
?>
```

Comment: can you do an echo $action; and check what is the page getting?

Comment: Acutally I didn't try this, but I did now, and it freaking worked, you're amazing, thanks! :)

Comment: @EddA. this is not good solution, you must not include things like `action=resetstats` in your URL. User can easily visit the page again later using that link and will reset his stats without his approval. if you have to do this, safest possible way is to include a token also that will expire after some seconds or so.

Comment: @Sharky For now that won't be a problem, if a user wants to reset their stats when it's already 0 then go ahead, but there's no point

Comment: @Sharky And those tokens you are talking about, I've been trying to make that for ages but never found out how, do you know how?

Comment: @Sharky, Yes I agree with that. Anything that is visible on the use and can be change is dangerous. but what we have is just the surface of his code and we still dont know how is he going to implement the security. But then again I agree with you.

Comment: @Schnebz encode a timestamp using a key, send the encoded timestamp with a hidden input, decode the timestamp, compare to current time, if its older than X seconds abort whatever trying to do. open a new question so i can answer on that, we are getting off-topic here :)

Comment: @Sharky Could you maybe post a sample code as an answer down below? :) Or maybe you could pastebin it or github and send me a link :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
<form>
.
.
.
    <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="resetstats">
</form>



<form>
.
.
.
    <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="changeprivacy">
</form>
```

and then

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') // if form is posted
{
    switch ($_POST['mode'])
   {
       case "resetstats":
           echo "your code to reset stats here";
       break;

       case "changeprivacy":
           echo "your code to change privacy here";
       break;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: @Schnebz be carefull, i ve seen you wrote in the question `I have set the id of the button to resetstats and changeprivacy` you need to change the `name` not the `id` of a input. `<input name="john" id="george">` that means that input can be accessed with `$_POST['john']`

Comment: What would I do for the button? Call it a submit button?

Comment: @Schnebz if a `<input type="submit" value="your text to be displayed on button here">` the button is a `input` with `type="submit"` and will post the form that is inside to. no need to name/id this